# dplyr text mining Column `text` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

Tags: r, text-mining, rapidminer

I'm experimenting with Tidytext ([Text Mining with R](https://www.tidytextmining.com/nasa.html#word-co-ocurrences-and-correlations)) and I want to use the function pairwise_count from the widyr library. My Input looks like:

[my input table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX1b2.png)

This is may code in the RapidMiner Execute R operator:

```
rm_main = function(data)
{
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(widyr)
set.seed(2017)

test <- data_frame(data) %>%
    pairwise_count(text, word)
    print(data)
 return(list(data))
}
```

When I execute the code I get the Error:
"Column `data` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list"

Is there maybe someone who can help me, please.

Regards
Tobias

Comment: Please `dput` and share your data.

Answer (score 0):

While I wait for details on your data set, I have noticed few errors in your code. e.g.:

1. If `data` parameter to function `rm_main` is `data.frame` then there is no need to convert it to `data.frame`.
2. `library` can be loaded at the very beginning of your code.
3. The parameters to function `pairwise_count` were not correct. The parameter should match the `column` name in `data.frame` or `data.table`

After correction, the function and its usage on a sample data will be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(widyr)

df <- data_frame(Id = rep(1:5, each = 2),
                  Text = c("a", "b",
                             "a", "c",
                             "a", "c",
                             "b", "e",
                             "b", "f"))
#define function 
rm_main = function(data)
{
  if(is.data.frame(data)){

    test <- data %>%
      pairwise_count(Text, Id)
  }
  print(data)
  return(list(data))
}

#call function now
rm_main(df)
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution solved this problem, but the function won't count any word pairs. I'll see in the Result Tab of RapidMiner my original table. Maybe I misunderstood this function.

Comment: @TobiasNehrig Glad to know that my solution solved your prob. Could you please provide your expected output as part of OP?

Comment: Well, I'd like to now which word pairs how often co-occur.